# GCP - Is there a way to get bill line items at Instance level

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, billing

GCP provides a mechanism to export billing data to BigQuery. This is really helpful but what it lacks is to provide cost line items at the Instance level (or at least I could not figure out a way). We can get cost aggregates at SKU, Project, Service level, but more granularity is required. This is very much possible with Azure and AWS.

Following are the columns I see in the exported BigQuery Billing table;

`billing_account_id, invoice.month, cost_type, service.id, service.description, sku.id, sku.description, usage_start_time, usage_end_time, project.id, project.name, project.ancestry_numbers, project.labels.key, project.labels.value, labels.key, labels.value, system_labels.key, system_labels.value, location.location, location.country, location.region, location.zone, cost, currency, currency_conversion_rate, , usage.amount, usage.unit, usage.amount_in_pricing_units, usage.pricing_unit, credits.name, credits.amount, export_time`

Is there a workaround to fetch cost aggregates at Instance level?

*Example: If I have subscribed for 2 Compute Engines of a specific SKU. Is there a mechanism to get cost aggregates for each Compute Engine separately?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment its not possible to filter your reports in instance level and **SKU** is the most granular filter.

An approach you can use to identify your instances and a get a better understanding of your data is using labels. As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels) :

> A label is a key-value pair that helps you organize your Google Cloud
> instances. You can attach a label to each resource, then filter the
> resources based on their labels. Information about labels is forwarded
> to the billing system, so you can break down your billing charges by
> label.

In this [document](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables#data-schema) which explains the billing data table's schema you can see that the labels attached in your resource will be present in your data.

[image]